# About writing a file using Do loop

Tags: export, output-formatting, files-and-directories

I want to write a file using `Do` loop. The loop computes a list of 9 functions whose outputs are floating point numbers. One of the functions produces large numbers which are generally expressed in scientific notation.

I intend to write the file in such a way so that while importing the file I can get a proper matrix output of $(n\times 9)$ where $n$ is the number of iterations.

I wrote the following code for $n=10$, but the output is not as per my expectation.

```
SetDirectory["E:\\"]; 
file2 = OpenWrite["file2.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm]; 
Do[F[i] = 
  N[{Cos[i]*Sin[i], Exp[i], i^2, Cos[i]*Exp[i], i, Sin[i] + Cos[i], 
    Log[i], Exp[Sin[i]], i^i}]; 
    Write[file2, F[i]]; , {i, 1, 10}]
Close[file2];
```

The output is

```
MatrixForm[Import["E:\\file2.dat"]]

(*{{0.454649,, 2.71828,, 1.,, 1.46869,, 1.,, 1.38177,, 0.,, 2.31978,, 1.}}

{{-0.378401,, 7.38906,, 4.,, -3.07493,, 2.,, 0.493151,, 0.693147,, 2.48258,, 4.}}

{{-0.139708,, 20.0855,, 9.,, -19.8845,, 3.,, -0.848872,, 1.09861,, 1.15156,, 27.}}

{{0.494679,, 54.5982,, 16.,, -35.6877,, 4.,, -1.41045,, 1.38629,, 0.469164,, 256.}}

{{-0.272011,, 148.413,, 25.,, 42.0992,, 5.,, -0.675262,, 1.60944,, 0.383305,, 3125.}}

{{-0.268286,, 403.429,, 36.,, 387.36,, 6.,, 0.680755,, 1.79176,, 0.756226,, 46656.}}

{{0.495304,, 1096.63,, 49.,, 826.754,, 7.,, 1.41089,, 1.94591,, 1.92897,, 823543.}}

{{-0.143952,, 2980.96,, 64.,, -433.729,, 8.,, 0.843858,, 2.07944,, 2.68951,}

{}

{7}

{1.67772, 10, }}

{{-0.375494,, 8103.08,, 81.,, -7382.96,, 9.,, -0.499012,, 2.19722,, 1.51001,}

{}

{8}

{3.8742, 10, }}

{10}

{{0.456473,, 22026.5,, 100.,, -18481.8,, 10.,, -1.38309,, 2.30259,, 0.58041,, 1., 10, }}*)
```

What I have understood is that the term $i^i$ (which produces large numbers, and therefore, whose outputs are expressed in scientific notation) is the main reason for such output (e.g., inclusion of extra rows). Unfortunately, I could not find a way to fix this and am eagerly waiting help.

Comment: I recommend `Export`.

Comment: @Carl Woll Thanks for all the necessary corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following. I writes the expression for the matrix into a .m file. For this, additional braces and commas have to be written to file, too. Writing also `` "Developer`ToPackedArray@" `` in front guarantees that the matrix is converted to a packed array when imported. Also leave away `FormatType -> OutputForm` opening the file.

```
F[i_] := N[{Cos[i]*Sin[i], Exp[i], i^2, Cos[i]*Exp[i], i, Sin[i] + Cos[i], Log[i], Exp[Sin[i]], i^i}];
n = 10;
file2 = OpenWrite["file2.m"];
WriteString[file2, "Developer`ToPackedArray@{\n"];
Do[
  Write[file2, F[i]];
  If[i < n, WriteString[file2, ",\n"]];,
  {i, 1, n}];
WriteString[file2, "}"];
Close[file2];
```

This my far not the most efficient way of writing and loading a matrix from file. Try also `Export` with formats with the Matlab matrix formal `MAT` or Mathematica's file dump format `MX`. These formats a binary and cannot be written line-by-line (as far as I know). See the docs for further details.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has solved my problem.

Comment: Fine! You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm), and do set [`PageWidth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PageWidth):

```
file2 = OpenWrite["file2.dat", PageWidth->Infinity];
Do[
    F[i] = N @ {
        Cos[i] Sin[i], Exp[i], i^2, Cos[i] Exp[i], i, 
        Sin[i]+Cos[i], Log[i], Exp[Sin[i]], i^i
    };
    Write[file2, F[i]],
    {i,1,10}
]
Close[file2];
```

Then:

```
Dimensions @ Import["file2.dat"]
```

> {10, 9}

Comment: Even after omitting `OutputForm`, I could not get the desired output.

Comment: @SoumyajitRoy I forgot I had used `SetOptions` on `OpenWrite`. Should work now.

Comment: I am sorry to say that this is still not the output which I am expecting, although the dimensions are {10,9}. Here is the difference with Henrik's code: https://i.imgur.com/X7RBPja.png